# How to solve error installing kivymd in Pydroid in NOX?

Tags: python, android-emulator, kivy, kivymd, pydroid

I was testing my Kivymd app with Pydroid 3, and then I thought it will be better if I can use Pydroid 3 on PC. So I installed the Nox emulator and installed Pydroid 3 app, and I tried to install `kivymd` with pip.

Then it said `Pydroid repository plugin is missing`, so I installed this plugin too.

And then it gives me so many errors, and the start of error, it says

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Pillow-7.12.dist-info'`, and end of error, it says `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'kivymd'
```

It's the same when I uncheck [Use prebuilt libraries repository] or reinstall Pydroid and plugin. How to solve this error?

I'm using Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply use kivymd on windows along with kivy, there is no need for an emulator, but it you want to use an emulator, I recommend BlueStacks

Answer (score 3):

Use Terminal instead of Pip menu. Open Pydroid, then open the side menu, tap on Terminal, then type "pip install kivymd==0.104.1".

Comment: solved my problem .